# Programatically add a reminder to the Reminders app

Tags: ios, eventkit, reminders

I'm creating a simple note application and I want to implement Reminders.  The user would type a note, tap a button and it would set up a reminder in the Reminders app using the text. Is this possible, and if so, how do I do it? I have seen Apple's documentation on EventKit and EKReminders but it has been no help at all.

Answer (score 18):

From the ["Calendars and Reminders Programming Guide"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)? Specifically ["Reading and Writing Reminders"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingReminders/ReadingAndWritingReminders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765-CH5-SW1)

> You can create reminders using the `reminderWithEventStore:` class method. The `title` and `calendar` properties are required. The calendar for a reminder is the list with which it is grouped.

Before you create a reminder, ask for permission:

In the `.h`:

```
@interface RemindMeViewController : UIViewController
{
    EKEventStore *store;
}
```

and the `.m`, when you are going to need access to Reminders:

```
store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder
                      completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                          // Handle not being granted permission
                      }];
```

To actually add the reminder. This happens asynchronously, so if you try to add a reminder immediately after this, it will fail (crashes the app in my experience).

```
- (IBAction)addReminder:(id)sender
{
    EKReminder *reminder = [EKReminder reminderWithEventStore:store];
    [reminder setTitle:@"Buy Bread"];
    EKCalendar *defaultReminderList = [store defaultCalendarForNewReminders];

    [reminder setCalendar:defaultReminderList];

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [store saveReminder:reminder
                                     commit:YES
                                      error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error saving reminder: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```